# How do I configure the Google Chrome / Chromium address bar to perform a search instead of trying to access a file on the local file system?

Tags: google-chrome, search, chromium, address-bar

How do I configure the Google Chrome / Chromium address bar to perform a search instead of trying to access a file on the local file system?  I would like to be able to enter a file name such as `/etc/hosts` or `/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts` in the address bar and to see Google search results for those file names similar to what I would see if I searched for the file names using something like https://www.google.com/#q=/etc/hosts

I am able to disable the file scheme using either of the following policy settings:

> "DisabledSchemes": ["file"],

Which has been deprecated in favor of:

> "URLBlacklist": ["file://"],

But in either case Google Chrome / Chromium continues to auto-detect that a file name was entered, automatically prepends the file scheme to the file name, and then reports that the webpage is blocked.

Comment: Do you have an example of a filename that it does that for?  I don't think what you're seeing is normal behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Knowing that the search was possible on some operating systems clued me in to using backslashes instead of forward slashes in the path.

Comment: Couldn't you just put either quotations (for verbatem search) or parentheses around your search term?  The latter *should* disqualify it as a URI while leaving the search results unaffected in the absence of search operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a workaround is to use backslashes `\` instead of forward slashes `/` in the path.

For example, in the address bar, instead of entering `/etc/hosts` or `/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts` search for `\etc\hosts` or `\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

This works even when referring to file systems (such as those found on OS X and Linux) that use forward slashes instead of backslashes.